# Automatically display an image according to a category

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column, 2019, image

I have a document list with 2 columns.
the first column is a category (Example: Menu, General, Information)
The second is an image.
I would like the image to be automatically calculated according to the selected category, but I can't do it.
I am a novice and I am learning to use SharePoint 2019.
What is the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1.You could create a calculated column with following formula:

```
=IF(menu="a","<DIV><img src='http://xx/sites/xx/SiteAssets/image1.png'></DIV>","<DIV><img src='http://xx/sites/xx/SiteAssets/image2.jpg'></DIV>")
```

Remember to select Number:

[image]

2.Then add a Script Editor Web Part with following codes to write HTML in to calculated column and convert HTML tag to image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//
// Text to HTML
// Feedback and questions: Christophe@PathToSharePoint.com
//
var theTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var i=0;
var TDContent = " ";
while (i < theTDs.length) {
try {
TDContent = theTDs&#91;i&#93;.innerText || theTDs&#91;i&#93;.textContent;
if ((TDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
theTDs[i].innerHTML = TDContent;
}
}
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
//
// ExpGroupRenderData overwrites the default SharePoint function
// This part is needed for collapsed groupings
//
function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {
var tbody=document.getElementById("tbod"+groupName+"_");
var wrapDiv=document.createElement("DIV");
wrapDiv.innerHTML="<TABLE><TBODY id=\"tbod"+ groupName+"_\" isLoaded=\""+isLoaded+ "\">"+htmlToRender+"</TBODY></TABLE>";
var theTBODYTDs = wrapDiv.getElementsByTagName("TD"); var j=0; var TDContent = " ";
while (j < theTBODYTDs.length) {
try {
TDContent = theTBODYTDs&#91;j&#93;.innerText || theTBODYTDs&#91;j&#93;.textContent;
if ((TDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
theTBODYTDs[j].innerHTML = TDContent;
}
}
catch(err){}
j=j+1;
}
tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapDiv.firstChild.firstChild,tbody);
}
</script>
```

My test result:

[image]

For Reference: [Add image to custom list with calculated / conditional column](http://sharepointpratik.blogspot.com/2011/06/add-image-to-custom-list-with_30.html)

Comment: The first part seems to work, but when I try to add a script with the "script editor" web component I got this error in my console log : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. I don't see where this error came from, since I have copy/paste your code.